# jqgrid loads on page load. But does not reload on a select list change

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that loads all employees' data on page load. There is a select list for departments. On changing the selection on that select list, the department's data is retrieved but it reloads the same all employees data again instead of the filtered data. How can I fix this?

```
$(function () {            
    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: 'EmployeeTransfer.aspx/getEmployeesOnLoad',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['Project Name', 'Project Code', 'Emp Code', 'Emp Name', 'Department', 'Designation', 'Stage', 'Id'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'ProjectName', index: 'ProjectName', width: 90, stype: 'text', sorttype: 'string', search: true },
            { name: 'CompCode', index: 'CompCode', width: 90 },
            { name: 'FullCode', index: 'FullCode', width: 100, sorttype: 'integer', search: true },
            { name: 'EmpName', index: 'EmpName', width: 260, sorttype: 'string', search: true },
            { name: 'department', index: 'department', width: 270, hidden: true },
            { name: 'designation', index: 'designation', width: 260, sorttype: 'string', search: true },
            { name: 'Stage', index: 'Stage', width: 260 },
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', key: true, width: 70, sorttype: "int",hidden:true },
        ],
        search: true,
        rowNum: 30,
        height: 700,
        sortname: 'Id',
        rownumbers: true,
        sortable: true,
        gridview: true,
        loadonce: true,
        pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        multiselect: true,             
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "Employee Details",
        onSelectRow: function (ids) {
            if (jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') > 0)
                {                          
                    var rowId = $("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    var rowData = jQuery("#jQGridDemo").getRowData(rowId);
                    var colData = rowData['EmpName'];
                    jQuery("#jQGridSelect").addRowData(rowId, rowData);
                }
        },
        serializeGridData: function (data) {
            return $.toJSON(data);
        }

    }).jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb');

    $("select#ddlDepts").change(function () {

        var dept = $(this).find(":selected").text().trim();
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "EmployeeTransfer.aspx/getEmployeesByDept",                   
            data: JSON.stringify({ strParam: dept}),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,                         
            success: function (data) {

                if (data != null) {

                    jQuery('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('clearGridData')
                          .jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: data, datatype: 'json' })
                          .trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
                }
            },
            error:
            function (x, e) {
                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
            }

       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve my problem.  For anyone struggling like me, below is the working code.

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data != null) {
        $('#jQGridDemo').clearGridData(true);
        $('#jQGridDemo').setGridParam({ 
            datastr: data.d, 
            datatype: 'jsonstring', 
            rowNum: data.d.length 
        }).trigger('reloadGrid'); 
    }
},
```

The format of my json string was as follows:

```
{
    "d": {
        "page": 0,
        "total": 2,
        "record": 2,
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "cell": [
                    " XXXX",
                    "107",
                    "902000707",
                    "XXXXXXXX",
                    "IT",
                    "SOFTWARE ENGINEER",
                    "Transfer 107 to 109",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "cell": [
                    "XXXX",
                    "108",
                    "902000164",
                    "XXXXXXXX",
                    "IT",
                    "IT ADMINISTRATOR",
                    "Transfer  108 to 107",
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "SortColumn": null,
        "SortOrder": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a postData param when configuring jqGrid e.g.:

```
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({ postData: { id: 1 } });
```

This id param would be posted to the server. Then in your callback from the ajax request, you can update the postData value e.g.:

```
jQuery('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('clearGridData')
                                  .jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { id: data.id } })
                                  .trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
```